# Strange line (like border) between two divs

Tags: html, css

**Strange line** apears between two divs. Cant rid of it. Please anyone tell me where im wrong?

My HTML

```
<div class="user_profile">
    <div class="up_openBtn">
        ICON
    </div>
    <div class="up_main">
        <div class="um_level">32</div>
        <div class="um_name">USERNAME</div>
        <div class="um_title">CONQUEROR</div>
        <div class="um_rank"><small>rank</small> 1430</div>
    </div>
    <div class="up_stats">
        <h1>Stats:</h1>
        <div class="us_atk">Attack: 2592</div>
        <div class="us_spd">Speed: 144</div>
        <div class="us_hp">Health: 9463</div>
        <div class="us_gm">Gold Multiplier: 2.3%</div>
        <div class="us_rm">Rune Multiplier: 4.6%</div>
    </div>
    <div class="up_runes">
        <div class="ur_slot1"></div>
        <div class="ur_slot2"></div>
        <div class="ur_slot3"></div>
        <div class="ur_slot4"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

.. and CSS

```
*,html,body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  color: var(--light0);
  font-family: "Montserrat", sans-serif;
  font-weight: 500;
}
.user_profile {
  padding: 48px;
  background-color: var(--dark0);
  width: fit-content;
  height: 100vh;
  position: relative;
}
.up_openBtn {
  background-color: var(--dark0);
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  transform: translateX(100%);
  padding: 24px;
}
```

https://i.stack.imgur.com/8NnyD.png <- what I see in browser

I will appreciate if anyone help! Тhank you in advance..

Comment: can you give a link of the live code?

Comment: https://codepen.io/kjelyazkov/pen/RwaRPrR @djangotic

Comment: i can see no strange border in codepen!

Comment: Which browser are you using. I can't see it in Chrome? You could add `* { border: none }` and try.

Comment: I tried from Chrome, Opera, Mozilla. Also tried to add ` * { border: none; }` but no result. Only when downscale my monitor to 1080p, it disappear..

Comment: Are you using NormalizeCSS or ResetCSS?

Comment: this is all of the code that I use. @MarkBurns

Answer (score 1):

This is a weird solution, but what if you move the second div to the left just a tinge? Maybe it's not actually a border, maybe it's just weird pixel aligning.

```
.up_openBtn {
    right: 1px;
}
```